# C: fgets return an extra blank line at beginning

Tags: c

I am trying to read a file and reverse each line of it and display it to standard output in C.

my file is:

```
$ cat f1
this is line 1
this is line 2
this is line 3
```

My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void reverse_string(char *s) {
    int l = strlen(s);
    int i;
    char sr[l];
    int j = 0;

    for (i = l - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        sr[j] = s[i];
        j++;
    }
    printf("%s", sr);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *fp;
    int i;
    char filename[128];
    char line[100];

    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        strcpy(filename, argv[i]);
    }

    fp = fopen(filename, "r");

    while (fgets(line, 128, fp) != NULL) {
        if (strlen(line) != 0) {
            reverse_string(line);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Output is:

```
$ ./mycode f1
(blank line here)
1 enil si siht
2 enil si siht
3 enil si siht
```

I am confused, why is there a extra blank line being output by my while loop even though there is no blank line in the file.

Comment: Where is the extra blank line in your output?

Comment: You moved the newline char to the start of the line, by design!

Comment: `while(fgets(line, 128, fp) != NULL)` line was only 100 bytes size. sizeof is your friend here

Comment: Avoid the name `l` for a variable: it looks confusingly close to `1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fgets includes a '/n' before nul char.

So when you reverse a string, the first thing you do is print it.

---

My ugly fix is:

replace the fist printf with

```
printf("%s\n", sr+1);
```

remove the second one.

---

And remember, when all fails, read the manual.:

> fgets() reads in at most one less than size characters from stream  and
> stores  them  into  the buffer pointed to by s.
>
> Reading stops after an EOF or a newline.  **If a newline is read, it is stored into the  buffer.**
>
> A  terminating  null  byte ('\0') is stored after the last character in the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

I am also trying to read from the file. My file contains the user's name and after reading username I need to add a constant character to each user. But when I am reading the file, I am getting unwanted empty lines in output and constant character is showing at empty line not together with the user name.

```
  int main()
{
char buffer[20] ;
char i, j;
const char *a="love";
FILE *fp;

if ((fp = fopen("user.txt","r")) == NULL)
{
     perror ("Error opening file");
}
     while ( !feof(fp))
   {
    // read in the line and make sure it was successful
    if (fgets(buffer,20,fp) != NULL)
    {
        cout << buffer  << endl;                
               for(i = 0; buffer[i] != '\0'; ++i);

               for(j = 0; a[j] != '\0'; ++j, ++i)  
               {
                   buffer[i] = a[j];
                }
        buffer[i] = '\0' ;

        //cout << buffer << endl ;
     }  
   }
}
```

I am getting output like this

```
asharma5
love
as23w
love
qwssdd
love
```

My desired output is adding love to each user name.

```
asharma5love
as23wlove
qwssddlove
```

Comment: Was the C++ tag removed from the question?